# HTTP Error 401.0 - Unauthorized You do not have permission to view this directory or page when running ASP.NET MVC 5 app from VS 2019 & IIS Express

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, localhost, visual-studio-2019, iis-express, http-status-code-401

We (two developers, two different PCs) are getting the following error when launching an ASP.NET MVC 5 app from VS 2019 (using IIS Express) on our respective localhosts.

This app has been working fine for years and about a week ago we added a new column to the database and it's respective MVC component, and it worked ok. But after doing a simple rebuild we now get the above error.

The app is is using anonymous authentication and we have checked the `web.config` and `applicationhost.config` files and the project properties (F4 within VS) and all is correct as far as 'anonymous
authentication enabled="true"' goes. The local web project folder has the correct user permissions and even tried running VS2019 as Administrator, different browsers and even the previous unchanged working version from Git hub on an entirely different machine.

We have trawled through countless posts here on SO and beyond and tried everything

Here is the page...

[image]

Comment: No matter how you described it as no code change, this error is most likely caused by the authorize attribute applied to an action. Go back to your code and review/debug.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/1611044/iis-error-401-0-unauthorized-after-upgrade-to-wind